# Connecting Crystal Reports to Oracle OCI Autonomous Database

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, oracle-apex, oracle-call-interface, oracle19c

Is there a way to connect Crystal Reports with oracle oci ATP

I have been trying somethings but they aren't correct in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try reviewing this document - https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/adw-connection-instructions-sap-bo.pdf

which explains how to setup BO server which is used by both BusinessObject clients and Crystal Reports to connect to ADW/ATP. Section 5 in the presentation/PDF covers using Crystal Reports.

Hope this helps.